# Loading JSON data at start of program c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, console-application, reload

I am trying to load the data that I have serialised into a JSON file. I want my program to work such that the data that was saved, is bought back into the programs memory once the console app is re-opened.

My classes are defined as can be seen below:

```
public class Student{
        public string StudentName { get; set; } 
        public Dictionary<string, int> GradesRecord = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        public Guid StudentId { get; set;    
    }

public class Subject{
        public string SubjectName { get; set; }
        public Guid SubjectId { get; set; }
        public int MaxMarkAvail;
    }

public class ClassOfStudents{
        public List<Student> Students = new List<Student>();
        public List<Subject> Subjects = new List<Subject>();
        public void AddSubject(Subject subjectName){
            Subjects.Add(subjectName);
        }
        public void AddStudent(Student studentName){
            Students.Add(studentName);
        }
    }
```

I have a method that saves the students grades.

```
private static void ConvertStudentGradesToJson()
        {
            var studentsgrades = ClassOfStudents.Students.Select(x => new { x.StudentName, x.StudentId, x.GradesRecord });

            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"StudentsGrades.JSON"))
            using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
            {
                writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                serializer.Serialize(writer, studentsgrades);
            }
        }
```

Now, when I close the program, the `StudentsGrades.JSON` file is created.

I want to know how to load this information back into the programs memory once this program is re-opened after being closed.

NOTE: I am new to JSON. Please do excuse my lack of knowledge as to how JSON works.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just load the file and deserialize it in your main method? Or are you asking how to read and deserialize JSON files?

Comment: Some sample JSON? You could use newtonsoft.Json from NuGet.

Comment: I don't how to  load the file and serialise it. Do I have to deserealize it then save it again in ClassOfStudents.Students? If yes, how do i do this?

Comment: Yes you would deserialize from Json you saved. But what is ClassOfStudents there?

Comment: BTW, why wouldn't you instead use a database? Using JSON file as a database is asking for trouble (unless you mean that you always deal with a few students only). If you still want as JSON, you can say use MongoDB as a database.

Comment: @Cetin Basoz Yes this is the next step. I am using JSON to learn the skill. Next step is using SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when reopen app call this method:

```
public void LoadJson(string filePath="@StudentsGrades.JSON")
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        List<Students> Students = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Students>>(json);
    }
}
```

NOTE: you should use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json)

Comment: Please note: For the above, you have to use 
"Newtonsoft.Json.dll"

Comment: @HamedNaeemaei, `List<Students> Students` have global scope in that case so OP can use it anywhere in his program.

Comment: @HamedNaeemaei Thanks for your answer. Problem now is it throws an exception saying another process is using the file in question. I am very sure it is referring to my `ConvertToJson()` method as this is where I have put the serialisation of the data in. I don't understand why this would cause a conflict in terms of concurrency, I thought the `LoadJson()` method would be executed at the beginning of the program. Any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: @Sam you should close StreamWriter (sw) and JsonTextWriter (writer) after write in ConvertStudentGradesToJson method

Comment: @Hamed Naeemaei Thanks, this compiles, however, it still doesn't load the data. One I close my console app and reopen it and view the students grades, it shows that there are no students there.  In essence, I want to be able to update the data, not overwrite